# Is there book or research on economically sustainable design of town or village?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, self-study

I'm looking for a book which may help to design a self-sustainable small  settlement, which can maintain its own economy with limited connections to the outside world. Prefereably it should answer questions like:

- What population is sufficient for such a town or village?
- How to model microeconomics of such a settlment?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the [*Handbook of Regional and Urban Economics*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/handbook/handbook-of-regional-and-urban-economics). It currently has 5 volumes and collects papers on the theories and empirics of urban/city design. Selected chapters that may potentially address your questions include:

- [City size and place as policy issues](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574008087800196)
- [Financing urban public services](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574008087800160)
- [The theory of urban residential location](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574008087800044)
- [Therories of urban business location](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574008087800056)
- [Urban labour markets](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157400809980008X)
- [Urban housing markets: Theory and policy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574008099800091)
- [Micro-Foundations of Urban Agglomeration Economies](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574008004800051)